# derived table in Hibernate native query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, nativequery, derived-table, hibernate-native-query

I have a native MySQL query with several join tables, including a derived table and Hibernate is failing to parse it.

```
SELECT 
 <select columns>
FROM
  (SELECT b.col as deriv_tbl_idx
   FROM b
   WHERE <some condition) deriv_tbl
STRAIGHT_JOIN
  c on (deriv_tbl_idx = c.id)
```

Hibernate throws the following exception

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column <column of the derived table open param [<select statement>]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:287)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:186)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:82)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getQueryParameters(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1260)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.getQueryParameters(NativeQueryImpl.java:163)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:149)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1410)
at org.hibernate.Query.getResultList(Query.java:427)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:372)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.getResultList(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:114)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:102)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:92)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
```

has anyone dealt with this issue before?

---

Comment: can you place the entire Query creation? With params set etc.

Comment: you mean you want the entire sql query? @MaciejKowalski

Comment: if you are using Hibernate then you do something like: session.createSQLQuery(query).setString().setInteger().list()..

Comment: I am using JPA hibernate